# How to make two timepickers behave like google calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I try to make my timepickers behave like the ones in google calendar. What I try to achieve is that if I set the start time from `10:00` to `11:00`, the `2nd` should follow from `11:00` to `12:00`. If I set the `2nd` picker from `11` to `13`, the difference is now `2` hours and if I adjust the first one, the `2nd` should move `+2` or `-2` hours depending if its earlier or later on the day.

My current jquery code is now

```
        var d = new Date();
        var start_time = $('#calendarentryform-start_time').val();
        var end_time = $('#calendarentryform-end_time').val();
        var diff = ( new Date('1970-01-01 ' + end_time) - new Date('1970-01-
        01 ' + start_time) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        var new_end_time = start_time + diff;


        $('#calendarentryform-start_time').on('change',function() {
                $('#calendarentryform-end_time').val(new_end_time);
            }
        );
```

It manage to find for example the hour difference on `1` hour, like the calculation is correct. But when I try to add that hour for `new_end`_time it just post `12:001` instead of `13:00` or whatever the time is supposed to be set to. I also want it to be able to find `1,5` hours, `2,5` hours etc.

I just dont seem to get it right.

Comment: Take  a close look at what `'1970-01-01 ' + end_time` produces.

Comment: @charlietfl I dont want to add dates, I found that by doing this I can find the difference between two numbers. Problem is it just returns for example 1. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Convert everything to Date objects, then do your maths on the Date objects, you'll have better luck.